# Caps Lock problem in Ubuntu VMWare virtual Machine

Tags: keyboard, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, capslock

I'm running a vmware virtual machine (not vmware pro) on which I have given 2 GB RAM from my laptop . The problem is whenever I press caps lock when writing text inside the virtual machine and I get capital letters when I press it again and I write some text I get mixed letters ex. (ExAMPLe instead of example )
I went to my vm settings but I didn't find something about my keyboard functionality . I would appreciate your help with helping me solve this problem . (feel free to ask for more info that I should include about the question )

Comment: me too. caps lock is not working on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding this line to the .vmx file for the Ubuntu VM:

```
mks.win32.useInjectedMagic=FALSE
```

Edit 2020-09-17: another user with the same problem had to apply a small adjustment, quoting the "FALSE" value:

```
mks.win32.useInjectedMagic = "FALSE"
```

Comment: worked for me on a Windows 8 host. The .vmx file is in c:/Users/<user>/Documents/Virtual Machines/<vmware machine name>/<vmware machine name>.vmx